# Is there a way to bypass "Before you continue to Google Search" using selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I've started using selenium to do web scrapping using google. I am getting started with the tutorials where the vast majority include the following basic steps:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
  
# Taking input from user
search_string = input("Input the URL or string you want to search for:")
  
# This is done to structure the string 
# into search url.(This can be ignored)
search_string = search_string.replace(' ', '+') 
  
# Assigning the browser variable with chromedriver of Chrome.
# Any other browser and its respective webdriver 
# like geckodriver for Mozilla Firefox can be used
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
  
for i in range(1):
    matched_elements = browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
                                     search_string + "&start=" + str(i))
```

However, I am getting the ["Before you continue to Google Search"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnwwr.jpg) pop-up which I haven't seen in most of the tutorials. I am aware that clicking the "I agree" button can be automated, but is that the only way to bypass the problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Execute your driver.get and add driver.find_element(By.ID, "L2AGLb").click()

Comment: Update the question with the HTML of the [**I agree**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnwwr.jpg) button.